# How to rsync files with matching pattern in path by keeping directory structure intact?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, rsync

I want to copy all files from server A to server B that have the same parent directory-name in different levels of filesystem hierarchy, e.g:

```
/var/lib/data/sub1/sub2/commonname/filetobecopied.foo
/var/lib/data/sub1/sub3/commonname/filetobecopied.foo
/var/lib/data/sub2/sub4/commonname/anotherfiletobecopied.foo
/var/lib/data/sub3/sub4/differentname/fileNOTtobecopied.foo
```

I want to copy the first three files that all have the `commonname` in path to server B. I already spent a lot of time in finding the correct include/exclude patterns for `rsync` but I dont get it. The following command does not work:

```
rsync -a --include='**/commonname/*.foo' --exclude='*' root@1.2.3.4:/var/lib/data /var/lib/data
```

I either match too much or to few of the files. How can I sync only the files with the `commonname` in its path?

Comment: You should probably ask this on the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange, or on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this:

```
rsync -a -m --include='**/commonname/*.foo' --include='*/' --exclude='*' root@1.2.3.4:/var/lib/data /var/lib/data
```

There are 2 differences with your command:

- The most important one is `--include='*/'`. Without this, as you specified `--exclude='*'`, `rsync` will never enter the subdirectories, since everything is excluded. With `--include='*/'`, the subdirectories are not excluded anymore, so `rsync` can happily recurse.
- The least important one is `-m`: this prunes the empty directories. Without this, you'd also get the (empty) subdirectory `/var/lib/data/sub3/sub4/differentname/` copied.