# How to properly match directories with rsync

Tags: rsync

I need to rsync some directories from one machine to another, but only part of the tree. I think the easiest way to explain it would be to run, on the server, `tree -f` (which prints the full path of each file) and then `grep`'ing *mon* in the full path and `rsynch`'ing only the matches of `grep`. Actually I would be happy to do it that way, but I don't have shell access to the server, only `rsync`. Two step solution based on `grep`ing output of `rsync --list-only` is totally acceptable.

It's actually simpler, because I also know that this *mon* appears **only** as a suffix to a directory (the hierarchy is pretty rigid), so I tried doing

`rsync --dry-run -vrlpt --include='*/' --include='**/*mon/' --exclude='*' --prune-empty-dirs`

but that did not match anything. Ditto for `--include='*mon/'` instead of the one with the double asterisk. Avoiding the `--prune-empty-dirs` matched all the directories but no files, which I think is my problem. So I tried to add an include pattern for some file extensions right before the exclude pattern (which I would rather not do because I don't want to track them all and they might change), but that simply matched all those files, including the ones not in the "mon" trees.

And yes, I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439393/how-to-rsync-files-with-matching-pattern-in-path-by-keeping-directory-structure) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2161/rsync-filter-copying-one-pattern-only/2503#2503) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63406/rsync-all-directories-that-start-with-a-specific-digit) and countless others, which helped me making some progress (i.e. what you can see above), but not solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following does the job (i.e. the problem was the matching of whatever is after mon) in the second include:

`rsync -arvm --include='*/' --include='*mon/***' --exclude='*' /path/to/source 
/path/to/dest`